# Passing a linked list head through a function as address in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I have a question regarding passing the head of a linked list in C through a function. So the code goes something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Defining a structure of the node
struct node { 
    int data;
    struct node* next;
    };

void insert (struct node* rec, int x) {
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    rec = temp; // head and rec is now pointing to the same node
}

void print(struct node* rec){
    printf("%d", rec->data); //error occurs here
    puts("");
}

main(){
    struct node *head = NULL; //head is currently pointing to NULL
    insert (head, 5); //Passing the head pointer and integer 5 to insert()
    print(head);
}
```

So as you see, the error occurs when I tried printing rec->data. Why did the error occur? I thought since the pointer rec and head are all pointing to the same node in the heap, there should not be any problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to pass `struct node**` to insert, like `insert(&head...`. Otherwise head will not change as the function only receives a copy of it's value.

Comment: You can the head of the list by pointer by redefining the `insert` function's parameters

Comment: Also, you might want `temp->next = *rec` (assuming you pass a double pointer) or you'll lose the rest of the list.

Comment: There are no references in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass a `struct node**` as suggested by @sje397.

However, I would suggest the following design (which, in my opinion is easier to reason about too):

```
/* returns the new head of the list */
struct node *insert (struct node* current_head, int x) {
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = current_head;
    return temp;
}
```

and use it like

```
head = insert(head, 5);
```

In this case I would also rename the function something like `push_front`.

Just for completeness, I think @sje397 meant something like the following (Typical linked list code rewritten again and again by every C programmer...):

```
void insert(struct node **head, int x) {
    struct node* new_head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_head->data = x;
    new_head->next = *head;

    *head = new_head;
}
```

Comment: I see... @sje397 nimrodm Thank you so much for the help! This pointer to pointer thing is getting me confused every time.

Answer (score 1):

In C there is no pass by reference.
Your insert function isn't inserting a node in the list, its just changing the node which the head points to. Because of `temp->next = NULL` the list will always contain two nodes.

Another error is that you're just modifying a local copy of the head node.
To fix this You have 3 choices:

-You can make the head node global

-You can pass a pointer to the head node(pointer to pointer) to the function.

-You can return the modified head node by the function.

Answer (score -1):

Redefine the `insert` function to:

```
void insert (struct node** rec, int x) {
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    *rec = temp; // head and rec is now pointing to the same node
}
```

Comment: That fixes the mentioned bug, but it's not an insert function.

Comment: Calling this function gives you nodes that point to `NULL`. So if you think about how a linked list is structured, this doesn't really offer insertion functionality. You need to modify `rec` so that the new node points to it, or vice versa.