# How to fix passing parameter address error in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Im trying to make a linked list and I want to insert a new node at the end by passing the address of head as parameter.

But, after the insert function ends, the head address didnt change and my linked list will always be NULL.
Here is the insert function:

```
// function to insert new node after the tail
void insertNode(node**headref, node**tailref, char studentNIM[], char studentName[], int attendance){
node*newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
printf("%p\n%p\n", *headref, *tailref); 
node*last = *headref;
strcpy(newNode->studentName, studentName);
strcpy(newNode->studentNIM, studentNIM);
newNode->attendace = attendance;
newNode->next = NULL;

if((*headref) == NULL){
    *headref = newNode;
    *tailref = newNode;
    printf("%p\n%p\n", *headref, *tailref);
    printf("%s", newNode->studentName);
    return;
}
while(last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;
last->next = newNode;
*tailref = newNode;
printf("%s", newNode->studentNIM);

}
```

Here is my entire code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h>

typedef struct data{
char studentNIM[13];
char studentName[33];
int attendace;
struct data*next;
}node;

//function prototypes
void printList(node*head);
void clear();
void enterCheck();
void addNode(node**headref, node**tailref);
void insertNode(node**headref, node**tailref, char studentNIM[], char studentName[], int attendance);
bool digitCheck(char studentNIM[]);

int main(){
int choice;
node*head = NULL;
node*tail ;
printf("%p\n%p\n", head, tail);
do{
    printf("\t\tStudent Attendance\n");
    printf("\t\t==================\n\n");
    printf("1. Add new student attendance.\n");
    printf("2. View student attendance.\n");
    printf("3. Exit.\n\n");
    printf("Choose menu: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    fflush(stdin);
    if(choice == 1)
        addNode(&head, &tail);
        printf("%p\n%p\n", head, tail);
    if(choice == 2)
        printList(head);
    if(choice == 3)
        return 0;
}while(choice != 3);
}

void addNode(node**headref, node**tailref){
char studentName[33];
int attendance;
char studentNIM[13];
node*head = *headref;
node*tail = *tailref;
printf("%p\n%p\n", head, tail);
do{
    printf("Enter student name(3 - 30 characters): ");
    fgets(studentName, 33, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
}while(strlen(studentName) < 4 || strlen(studentName) > 31);

do{
    printf("Enter student NIM(in number with length of 10 characters): ");
    fgets(studentNIM, 13, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
}while(digitCheck(studentNIM) == false || strlen(studentNIM) != 11);
printf("Enter number of presence: ");
scanf("%d", &attendance);
fflush(stdin);
insertNode(&head, &tail, studentNIM, studentName, attendance);
}
bool digitCheck(char studentNIM[]){
int i;
for(i = 0;i < strlen(studentNIM) - 1;i++){
    if(isdigit(studentNIM[i]) == false)
        return false;
}
return true;
}

// function to insert new node after the tail
void insertNode(node**headref, node**tailref, char studentNIM[], char studentName[], int attendance){
node*newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
printf("%p\n%p\n", *headref, *tailref);
node*last = *headref;
strcpy(newNode->studentName, studentName);
strcpy(newNode->studentNIM, studentNIM);
newNode->attendace = attendance;
newNode->next = NULL;

if((*headref) == NULL){
    *headref = newNode;
    *tailref = newNode;
    printf("%p\n%p\n", *headref, *tailref);
    printf("%s", newNode->studentName);
    return;
}
while(last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;
last->next = newNode;
*tailref = newNode;
printf("%s", newNode->studentNIM);

}

void printList(node*head){
if(head == NULL){
    printf("No data.\n");
    return;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what i was doing wrong?

Comment: Check this link Sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283200/passing-a-linked-list-head-through-a-function-as-address-in-c

Comment: You have a reference to tail already, it makes no sense to iterate from head to tail all over!!

Comment: All you need is `if (*headref == NULL) *headref = newnode; else (*tailref)->next = newnode; *tailref = newnode;`

Comment: Unrelated, whatever text/site/instructor told you `fflush(stdin);` was how to clear the `stdin` buffer, they're wrong. `fflush` is only standard-supported on *output* -enabled streams. The good news: most of them in this code are worthless anyway, even if they *did* work as you expect, so take the time to get rid of them and clean out `stdin` properly by consuming and discarding through newline in few places it is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

> But, after the insert function ends, the head address didnt change and my linked list will always be NULL.

The reason is that you call `insertNode` with the wrong argument.

You do:

```
insertNode(&head, &tail, studentNIM, studentName, attendance);
```

but `head` is a **local** variable in the function `addNode` so it can't change `head` in `main`. In other words, your call of `insertNode` will only change `addNode:head` - not `main:head`.

Maybe you wanted to do:

```
insertNode(headref, &tail, studentNIM, studentName, attendance);
           ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: More to the point, `head` and `tail` in `addNode` are *worthless*.  The OP should just get rid of them and fix up the code thereafter.